# Automatically generate a swager file for node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, swagger

I have a node express RESTfull api writen in typescript. 
Is there a tool that can automatically generate a swager file for my project based on the source code?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using ex. github, you should read their README, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#github-integration

Comment: I'd suggest you taking a look at this: https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 plug-ins that allow you to generate OpenAPI/Swagger specifications from the Node.js code:

1. https://github.com/readmeio/swagger-inline
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one-time way to do this, as opposed to  automating the process, you can also make calls to your API with [Swagger Inspector](https://inspector.swagger.io/), and create an API Definition from the call history.